# Using python pandas data frame, how do you delete all rows that contain a '-'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing a .csv file that someone else made, and they filled in some rows with a '-' character wherever there was missing data. The data frame looks something like this:

```
        Data1    Data2
0       99       1
1       99       2
2       -        3
3       98       4
4       97       5
5        -       -
6        -       -
```

Except it's more in the thousands of rows so I don't want to manually search for each row containing a dash to delete it. I have tried the following lines of code but it keeps returning an non altered data frame with the '-' rows still remaining:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    
df[df['Data1'] != '-']

print(df)
```

My logic is here is that any row not containing a '-' should remain, but clearly that's not working. The output I want is:

```
        Data1    Data2
0       99       1
1       99       2
2       98       4
3       97       5
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to keep the rows that are not ([`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)) `-` in [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) columns per row:

```
out = df[df.ne('-').all(axis=1)]
```

If for some reason you want to `drop` (e.g. to update in place), you can use:

```
m = df.eq('-').any(axis=1)
df.drop(df.index[m], inplace=True)
```

output:

```
  Data1 Data2
0    99     1
1    99     2
3    98     4
4    97     5
```